# forwarding HTTPS from Plesk to AWS EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, https, plesk, forwarding

I'am quite new to setting up and managing websites, domains and stuff.

I purchased a domain (let's say example.de) and registerd it on my vserver running Parallels Plesk. As I need secure access I requested and created a SSL-Certificate at startssl.com. The developed application (Spring-Boot) runs on an EC2-Instance at AWS. The Product-Website runs on an Apache-Webserver on an EC2 instance. I need to secure both, the App (app.example.de) and the Website (example.de) using SSL.

What I want to archive is a redirect from the domain https://example.de to the EC2 Instance. I already tried several things - some I remember from the try&error marathon

- Configure Plesk frame-forwarding the traffic on https://example.de to the ec2-ip

Obviously the Browser warns me that the Certificate is issued for example.de and not for  and classifies the traffic as unsecure. Same like when accessing it like https://...

- I also uploaded the certificate at Plesk - Also without success

Is there a solution for my setup? Or do I need (or is it recommened) to use Amazon Route53 for that task? Would be nice if someone could guide me and provide some tipps as I am pretty new to this topics.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way around AWS route 53.

I figured out that there is a Extension for Plesk that is designed to route traffic using route53 and even a [nice manual article](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=72230.htm) at the Plesk homepage how to use any external DNS and also Route53 Extension. As this Extension requires a newer version of Plesk, than that one I am using I wasn't able to install it. I am pretty much bound to this version, so an update didn't come into question. I cannot tell for sure if using this Extension solves my initial problem, but it seems to be a potential solution.

**The most simplistic solution** (at least for me):

I ended up moving my Domain the AWS, created a Hosted-Zone, Added a Record Set with the IP of the EC2 and the DNS Server provided due the hosted Zone. Everything is now working like a charm.

**Some more Background:** The Product-Website and App-Frontend are running inside an Apache where I installed mod_ssl and configured SSL access. The Application backend runs as a Spring-Boot-App in a Tomcat where I also configured SSL using a TomcatConnectorCustomizer.

This setup works for my scenario